# Python Create a simple library wrapper (as a side package)

Tags: python, pandas, module, wrapper

I need to extend a library's functionality (let it be pandas, for example). It works if I put my code inside `...site-packages/pandas/__init__.py`  (however, the code I added will be auto erased with the next pandas upgrade )

Struggle:
So, I need a wrapper library around pandas that I can call
with `import my_wrapper as pd` - how do I do that?

Current solution: create a module folder **my_wrapper** in site-packages with **`__init__.py`**:

```
import pandas
from pandas.core.base import PandasObject

def has_stackoverflow(ser: pandas.Series):
    return ser[ser.str.contains('stackoverflow', case=False, regex=True)]

PandasObject.has_stackoverflow = has_stackoverflow
# now, this method is available on any pandas object:
# pd.pandas.Series(['s','as stackoverflow sa']).has_stackoverflow()
```

WORKING IMPORT:

```
from my_wrapper import pandas as pd
```

DESIRED IMPORT:

```
import my_wrapper as pd
```

how do I achieve it?